# This "choose" function in Lua always results in nil

Tags: lua

From the past this code does work then suddenly the function results the variables to nil.

```
function choose(n1,n2)
    local r = math.random(1,2)
    if not n1 or not n2 then error("Choosing a number or a string results in nil.") end -- error if nil
    if r<1.5 then
        return n1
    else
        return n2
    end
end
function choose(v1,v2,v3)
    local r = math.random(1,3)
    if not v1 or not v2 or not v3 then error("Choosing a number or a string results in nil.") end --error if nil
    if r==1 then
        return v1
    elseif r==2 then
        return v2
    else
        return v3
    end
end

local Red,Yellow=2,12
choose(Red,Yellow)
```

The error that i get is;

```
File: "C:\Users\My Computer\Desktop\test.lua" line 3,
    Choosing a number or a string results in nil.
```

Answer (score 4):

Lua does not have function overload. It will assume you are updating the function and always calls the most recently defined.

In in your example, will raise the error because v3 is not defined.